# Cheapest ARM with an MMU

Tags: arm, linux

What is the cheapest ARM processor with an MMU so I don't have to use uCLinux?
Bonus for non-bga and integrated RAM/Flash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Atmel AT91SAM9260B comes in a LQFP package and may be a little bit lower in price than the SAM9G20.  It has a MMU and the same peripherals as the SAM9G20 but runs at 200 MHz rather than a max of 400 MHz.  Pay attention to the details in the Atmel Application note Schematic Checklists and you will be successful.

You could also try the AT91SAM9XE512 with flash on-chip.  But 512KB isn't going to be enough even for uCLinux, so the most cost effective thing to do is use the flash-less SAM9G20 or SAM9260B with external flash and SDRAM.

http://www.atmel.com/at91

Comment: if it has an mmu the amount of on-chip memory becomes irrelevant, as you can use an ipt algorithm to swap out code from a serial flash.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is chips in the ARM926EJ-S family, like the [AT91SAM9G20](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=4337). The G20 costs around $10 in relatively low quantity, and it has an MMU. Unfortunately, it's only available in a BGA package, and you'll need external memory.

The good news is that the ball pitch on the G20 is 0.5 mm (edit: there's a 0.8 mm pitch version too), which is just within the limit of what most assembly houses will do without a surcharge. If you go to an ARM Cortex A8, like the OMAP35xx, you have to deal with 0.4 mm ball pitch.

There are at least 5 companies that are making SBCs using the G20. Here are a few:

- [Emac SoM-9G20](http://www.emacinc.com/som/som9G20.htm), Illinois, USA
- [Taskit Stamp9G20](http://www.taskit.de/en/products/stamp9g20/index.htm), Berlin, Germany
- [Propox MMnet1002](http://www.propox.com/products/t_232.html?lang=en), Poland

(I'm actually working on an open hardware board based around this chip, but it won't be ready for a few months at least. But that at least explains why I have all this crap in my head!)

Answer (score 6):

The AT91RM9200 used to be a popular choice (ARM9 + MMU). It's non-BGA, but doesn't have integrated RAM/Flash.

http://opencircuits.com/Linuxstamp

Answer (score 4):

The imx233 freescale processor costing around 10$ and is available in 128LQFP package

Answer (score 1):

There are two another choices there: 
1. Vybrid VF3xx ARM Cortex-A5 family from Freescale (now NXP), main features: 266MHz, 1.5MB on-chip SRAM, 2x Ethernet + L2 switch, **LQFP176**. 
2. RZ/A1 ARM Cortex-A9 family from Renesas, they have few ICs with LQFP package (176, 208, 256 pins), and large on-chip SRAM (3MB-10MB), 400MHz.
You can get it from DigiKey for example.