# Tips on parts for a very low power LED blinker

Tags: pcb, batteries, low-power

I'm looking into designing a badge for a tech conference and we're thinking of creating a small PCB with one or more LEDs on it.

Requirements:

- Less than $5 per unit for 2500 badges
- The PCB has to be around the size of a 3.5" floppy with place to add a sticker with the participant's name of it
- A silk layer would be nice to show of the parts and complete the "geek" feeling
- Ideally it would run on a "button"/"cell" battery, but a AAA battery might be needed.
- It would be nice if it would run for up to a year, but the conference is two days so anything that would run for at least three days is doable

Options we're thinking of:

- Blinking a single red LED
- One "glowing" RGB led that changes between the three different colors of the event's design
- A strip of RGB LEDs making the whole badge "glow"
- Using some kind of plastic to use less LEDs to illuminate more of the badge

The question is: what kind of architectures should I look into?

The LM3909 is supposed to be nice, but out of production. Are there any replacement components like that?

For stuff that glows I see two possibilities some MCU (MSP430 perhaps?) to do PWM between one or three colors or use a D/A to set the voltage of the LED to an appropriate level.

Comment: Sounds like a budget (read: boring) [DEFCON badge](http://www.google.com/search?q=DEFCON+badges).

Comment: Hm, didn't know of those. I'll see if I can learn something from those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The six-pin SOT-23 [PIC10F200](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en019863) is $0.32 for 1ku, and can use a supply down to 2V. That would be a good choice. If you need PWM it could be implemented in software, as the device includes a timer.

Another option would be the similar [ATtiny4](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?category_id=163&family_id=607&subfamily_id=791&part_id=4605) from Atmel. It has more features, including PWM, but is more expensive at over $0.50 for 1ku.

Comment: Also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8676/what-are-the-cheapest-microcontrollers

Answer (score 1):

The MSP430G2211 is under 50c in 1ku quantities. It could be a good fit.
Here are a couple of my own flashing LED projects based on it.

[RGB Lamp](http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/09/30/jam-jar-lamp/), [LED Chaser](http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/09/12/577/)

But, for a flashing LED, a 555 could be the obvious choice.

Comment: How much do you think the total current draw would be for a PWM controlled RGB LED from a 1.5V battery?

Comment: It would depend on the microcontroller and LED, you'd have to consult the datasheets

Comment: You'd need to step up the voltage from a 1.5V battery.  See Vf in the table: http://www.kpsec.freeuk.com/components/led.htm#data . 3V is a better choice.

Comment: A nice variation on binary code modulation, which I'm surprised I haven't often seen implemented in hardware, is to output the MSB on every other sample, the next bit on every other sample among those remaining, etc.  This gives a cleaner steady-state signal than PWM, though updating the output value smoothly can be tricky.  As with BCM, many bits can be handled in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

With some RFID components, you can do things like automated people tracking:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/blinkenarea/4800793412/]

http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2010/06/hacking-next-hope-badge.html

I think thats a more interesting use of technology than yet another Blinking Bow Tie: 
[image]

Comment: And you can sniff Microsoft wireless keyboards... http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2011/02/promiscuity-is-nrf24l01s-duty.html

Comment: We have used RFID cards for many years, and while fun they're more expensive. This year each visitor will get its own [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) which we'll scan on entrance and for participation in the different quizzes.

Comment: Depending on the type of tech conference, you might get parts donated for PR value.  That's how the Next HOPE badge was funded.